# convert mysql query to laravel builder 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

```
SELECT user_id, email, username, password, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM users
where email = 'dyz@dss.com'
GROUP BY password HAVING count > 0
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

I tried with below code does not work Please guide how to do this thanks in advance

```
User::SELECT('user_id, email, username, password, COUNT(*) AS count')
                                    ->where('email', Input::get('username'))
                                    ->groupBy('password')
                                    ->havingRaw('count > 0')
                                    ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
                                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

```
DB::table('users')
                                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count, user_id, email, username, password'))
                                    ->where('email', Input::get('username'))
                                    ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
                                    ->groupBy('password')
                                    ->having('count', '>', 0)
                                    ->get();
```